# How do I generate a stable unique ID in React with SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using SSR in Next.js. I'm trying to generate a unique ID in a component to use in a DOM element's `id` attribute. This component may be used multiple times on a page so each component instance needs its `id` to be unique. However, doing something like the following on each render of the component results in a server/client mismatch (component creates new ID on each render, so server and client do not match):

```
const gradientId = `linear-gradient-${uuid().slice(0, 8)}`
```

Stuff I've tried:

- generating the ID as a default useState value
- generating the ID right outside the component (same file, just above component definition)
- generating the ID inside a `useMemo`

All seem to suffer from the client/server mismatch issue. Is there a good way to do this? Is there something stable in the component instance I can base the ID on instead (maybe React generates one I can use?).

I should also note I’m stuck on React 17 so I don’t have access to React 18’s [useId](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useId), which seems aimed at solving this exact problem!

Any ideas appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You can wrap whatever function creates it client side in use callback with an empty dependancy array and it won't change on state updates

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately this didn’t work out and I still get the error when using useCallback(). I think I’ve misunderstood this aspect of SSR. I was under the assumption that the server render and initial client render were the same component instance (render #1 on server, render #2 on client). This doesn’t seem to be the case though and each render comes from a completely distinct component instance! I’ve got an idea about switching away from random IDs entirely – will report back!

Comment: Ah - I thought you were passing the uuid to the backend and it was the frontend that was randomizing it. Mea culpa

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may be a better solution out there, but the key appeared to be in abandoning a random ID in favour of a more deterministic ID like an index.

Outside of my component (in the same file, just above the component definition), I can define a function to generate the ID and I can seed it with 0.

```js
let sequentialId = 0
const getSequentialId = function() {
    return sequentialId++
}

function MyComponent({ ...otherProps }) {
   ...etc...
}
```

then, in my component, I can simply call this instead of the uuid() function I was previously calling:

```js
const gradientId = `linear-gradient-${getSequentialId()}`
```

This forces the server render to generate 0, 1, 2, etc. and then when the client runs (remember client instances are brand new component instances), it will also start at 0 and sequentially assign IDs in the same order as the server.

I’ve gone one step further and moved this function to a provider where it can be called from any component in case I need this again:

```js
const PageSettingsContext = React.createContext({
    _sequentialId: 0,
    getSequentialId: function() {
        return this._sequentialId++
    },
})

function usePageSettings() {
    return useContext(PageSettingsContext);
}

function PageSettingsProvider({ ...otherProps }) {
    return (
        <PageSettingsContext.Provider>
            <App />
        </PageSettingsContext.Provider>
    );
}

export {
    PageSettingsProvider,
    usePageSettings,
}
```

This seems to clear up the error and hopefully this holds up over time. Any other ideas or insights welcome but think this works for me.

Comment: Right now there's `useId` react API.